# Sentry log4j throws error 405 not allowed

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, liferay, sentry

I'm trying to setup java log4j sentry on local liferay 6.2 tomcat 7.0.62 and still getting error 405 not allowed.

This is log from liferay server

```
09:39:39.383 [raven-pool-1-thread-4] WARN : Lockdown started for 327680ms.
09:39:39.383 [raven-pool-1-thread-1] WARN : An exception due to the connection occurred, a lockdown will be initiated.
com.getsentry.raven.connection.ConnectionException: <html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.2</center>
</body>
</html>
    at com.getsentry.raven.connection.HttpConnection.doSend(HttpConnection.java:156)
    at com.getsentry.raven.connection.AbstractConnection.send(AbstractConnection.java:86)
    at com.getsentry.raven.connection.AsyncConnection$EventSubmitter.run(AsyncConnection.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://sentry.company.cz/api/5/store/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at com.getsentry.raven.connection.HttpConnection.doSend(HttpConnection.java:148)
    ... 5 more
```

This is my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Console, SentryAppender

log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p: %m%n

log4j.appender.SentryAppender=com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender
log4j.appender.SentryAppender.dsn=http://private:public@sentry.company.cz/5
log4j.appender.SentryAppender.tags=tag1:value1,tag2:value2
```

I'm connected to VPN, I've reinstalled certificates, but with no result. It fails when deploying to liferay server. Does anyone know what to do with it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in that i had to use https instead of http. It took me way too much time to figure out

EDIT:

In liferay server log, there is still exception, that it couldn't find host, but at sentry web app, it correctly logs all errors.

Comment: Is this self-hosted Sentry?

Comment: It is company sentry, where I need to be on VPN to even find a sentry server. 
In liferay server log it still throws exception, but at sentry web app it logs all errors